# ValueError: Data must not be a string. in Python

Tags: python

```
   "Guys am trying python requests module to automate SOAP request and need help with it..Basically this is what i am doing. "

    body = '''<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
    ...some code here....
    </rel:SubmitReq>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
    '''

    files={ }
    with open("/home/xxx/yyy/zzz.jpg", "rb") as f:
        files = base64.b64encode(f.read())

    headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml","Connection":  "Keep-Alive", "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="}

    r = requests.post('URL PAth', verify=False, headers=headers, data=body,files=files)

    print r.status_code

    print r.content
```

'''The problem is we are always getting ValueError: Data must not be a string.

can someone guide me as to what could be the problem'''

Comment: That's not a RESTful service, you may need to take a look at other libraries like `suds`.

Comment: ekhumoro .. if you mark something duplicate.. send the original link as well.

Comment: yes this is not REST .. this is soap.. not sure why that should matter..  ettanany

Comment: With `requests` you can only send `HTTP` requests

Comment: We have fixed the issue

Comment: We have fixed the issue .. the solution really is finding encoding which will be accepted by server..  nothing to do with REST or SOAP..